# Python - Manipulating numbers for a round number and create new column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the following question I would like to ask:

EXAMPLE:

```
INITIAL DATA

DATE        EMAIL                SALE
10/2/2020   ABC@gmail.com        $  501.00 
10/2/2020   123@gmail.com        $  100.00 
10/2/2020   test@gmail.com       $  50.00 
10/2/2020   example@gmail.com    $  32.00 
10/2/2020   ABC@gmail.com        $  501.00 
10/3/2020   test@gmail.com       $  45.00 
10/3/2020   123@gmail.com        $  75.00 
10/3/2020   example@gmail.com    $  100.00 
10/4/2020   example@gmail.com    $  200.00  

DESIRED OUTPUT

DATE       EMAIL             SALE     CHECKED LEFT?   
10/2/2020  ABC@gmail.com     $501.00  $500.00 $1.00   
10/2/2020  123@gmail.com     $100.00  $100.00 $0.00   
10/2/2020  test@gmail.com    $50.00   $50.00  $0.00   
10/2/2020  example@gmail.com $32.00   $30.00  $2.00   
10/2/2020  ABC@gmail.com     $501.00  $500.00 $1.00   
10/3/2020  test@gmail.com    $45.00   $40.00  $5.00   
10/3/2020  123@gmail.com     $75.00   $70.00  $5.00   
10/3/2020  example@gmail.com $100.00  $100.00 $0.00   
10/4/2020  example@gmail.com $200.00  $200.00 $0.00
```

I want to create new columns as a counter to mark if it is a smooth number that ends in a around number -  EX. 10, 500 it will be counted and put in a column called checked. Then the left over remaining sales will be put in a column called left? and a counter to indicate it was counted or not.

I am new to manipulating data in python so I'm unsure what I can even google to do this.

Any help would be appreciated or if you guys have suggestions as well!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you post the code of your attempts so far?

Comment: Hey - I don't even know where to start because I don't know what to look for - If there is anything you can suggest that would be great!

Comment: Why is line 2 counted and line 3 not?

Comment: oh sorry thats a mistake! - corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['SalesNum'] = df['SALE'].str.strip('$').astype(float)
df['MARKED'] =  (df['SalesNum'] // 10) * 10
df['LEFT$'] = df['SalesNum'] % df['MARKED']
df['COUNTED'] = (df['MARKED'] > 0).astype(int)
df
```

Output:

```
        DATE            EMAILID       SALE  SalesNum  MARKED  LEFT$  COUNTED
0  10/2/2020      ABC@gmail.com  $  501.00     501.0   500.0    1.0        1
1  10/2/2020      123@gmail.com  $  100.00     100.0   100.0    0.0        1
2  10/2/2020     test@gmail.com   $  50.00      50.0    50.0    0.0        1
3  10/2/2020  example@gmail.com   $  32.00      32.0    30.0    2.0        1
4  10/2/2020      ABC@gmail.com  $  501.00     501.0   500.0    1.0        1
5  10/3/2020     test@gmail.com   $  45.00      45.0    40.0    5.0        1
6  10/3/2020      123@gmail.com   $  75.00      75.0    70.0    5.0        1
7  10/3/2020  example@gmail.com  $  100.00     100.0   100.0    0.0        1
8  10/4/2020  example@gmail.com  $  200.00     200.0   200.0    0.0        1
```

Details:

- First let's strip the string in 'SALES' column of the dollar sign
  using the `.str`, the string accessor and `strip` and casting that
  result as a float datatype and assign this to 'SalesNum' column.
- Next, we can use `//` the floor divide to get an integer for the
  number of times 10 will divide evenly in to the 'SalesNum' column.
  And we multiple that result by 10 to get 'MARKED'.
- Now, we can use `%` the modulo operator to get the remainder after we
  divide 'SalesNum' by 'MARKED'.
- Lastly, we assign 1 to counted if any value greater than zero was
  assigned to 'MARKED'.

Comment: Thank you!! I think this works!! Can you explain a little what you did here - df['SalesNum'] % df['MARKED'] - how did that allow us to get the reminder?

Comment: @user13904208 Thanks.   I had planned on adding this explanation but, I got distracted by my kids.  Here it is I hope it helps.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Scott! This was really informative!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to string and do some string manipulation replacing the last digit with 0 and then convert back to int"

1. I created a series `s` that essentially counts how many digits there are, which you will use in the next step t oadd that number of zeros.
2. When creating the `MARKED` column, I took the first digit with `.str[0]` and added the required number of zeros from `s`.

---

```
# df['SALE'] = df['SALE'].replace(['\$', '\..*'], '', regex=True).str.strip().astype(int)

s = (df['SALE'].astype(str).map(len) - 1).apply(lambda x: x * '0')
df['MARKED'] = (df['SALE'].astype(str).str[0]  + s).astype(int)
df['LEFT$'] = df['SALE'] - df['MARKED']
df
Out[1]: 
        DATE            EMAILID  SALE  MARKED  LEFT$
0  10/2/2020      ABC@gmail.com   501     500      1
1  10/2/2020      123@gmail.com   100     100      0
2  10/2/2020     test@gmail.com    50      50      0
3  10/2/2020  example@gmail.com    32      30      2
4  10/2/2020      ABC@gmail.com   501     500      1
5  10/3/2020     test@gmail.com    45      40      5
6  10/3/2020      123@gmail.com    75      70      5
7  10/3/2020  example@gmail.com   100     100      0
8  10/4/2020  example@gmail.com   200     200      0
```

Comment: what if the last digit is not a 0 for example its 539 - how would you tackle the 39 then?

Comment: @user13904208 are you trying to take the floor or if above 5 you would round up? In the row with 45, you rounded down to 40, so I assumed you were taking floor. 539 would become 530. Would 539 become 500?

Comment: yes - I am trying to keep it all the way to either 500 or 300 or 200 or 100 and not with 549 or 583

Comment: interesting - if you don't mind can you explain a little what you did ? I think I see it as you split the str and then applied 0 to the str?

Comment: @user13904208 by the way Scott's answer is much better, so feel free to accept that.